# "They don't need to be questions"?

Tags: discussion, meta, asking-questions

From time to time on various meta sites, I see someone reminding folks that posts on meta sites are not required to be questions.

Would it be too difficult to change the text in the buttons for "Questions" and "Ask Question" on the meta sites?  This would reduce the need for such reminders.

But is there even a need for such a reminder?  Someone seems to think so.

Comment: What do you propose they be called instead?

Comment: I don't propose anything.  But I do notice that one or more persons has reason to think we need to be reminded.  I also notice that any post with the audacity to even ask a question like this gets downvoted in a really big hurry.  SE is great, but it will never be perfect and downvoting folks who you think are criticizing it won't change that.

Comment: I only said "feature-request" because I certainly don't consider it a bug.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek "Open new topic" or "Create a post" sound like a suitable option.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I guess that they are because you're stating a perceived problem 1) without references to back it up 2) without a concrete solution (especially since you tagged it [feature-request] instead of [discussion]).

Comment: It's happened many times on various metas.  I ask about something or suggest a possible change and someone reprimands me and/or several downvote without explanation.

Comment: Ten unexplained downvotes here.  An example of the phenomenon I described.  If it's remotely possible that the post can be interpreted as a suggestion of imperfection, what seems to be defensiveness arises.

Comment: No one is reprimanding, at least not in how I perceive what is said here. The only issue is that you bring something up that *could be* a problem without one or two examples and how that *reminding of folks* actually is causing too much noise.

Comment: Examples?  If I've seen it several times, I'm sure others have seen it.  If I could remember the exact words and put them in the search, would it find them in comments?

Answer (score 10):

> I see someone reminding folks that posts on meta sites are not required to be questions.

Does this ever lead to confusion? I bet that 99% of the "topics" on Meta, if they're actually in scope, can be rewritten as

- [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion): What should I/we do about X?
- [support](/questions/tagged/support): How does X work?
- [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request): Can we have X?
- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug): Can you please fix X?

The only exceptions I know of are the [announcements](/questions/tagged/announcements) by the company Stack Overflow. Those are posted by employees and they're not likely to be confused (though there has been some discussion about the on-topicness of some announcements in the past).

Comment: Good question; does it?  One or more persons seem to think we need to be reminded.

Comment: [meta-tag:announcements]: We're now Xing, don't you love it?

Comment: So if a post that can't be reworded as a question is off-topic, then why these reminders that they don't have to be questions?